# Golang - Gin BindJSON to []byte

Tags: api, go, model, go-gorm, go-gin

**Question**: I'm using GORM and the Gin Web Framework to create a RESTful API. I'm trying to bind the body of a JSON request with `BindJSON` to the model, but the model contains a slice of byte leading to an error. How can I bind the body to the model without changing the datatype to string?

Model:

```
type User struct {
    Password []byte `json:"password" binding:"required"`
}
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "password": "mypassword"
}
```

Controller:

```
r.PUT("/user", func(c *gin.Context) {
    var user User
    err := c.BindJSON(&user)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
})
```

**Error**: illegal base64 data at input byte 12

This error appears, as Gin tries to bind a `string` (from the JSON body) to a `[]byte` (from the model) and fails.

**Solution that I don't like**:
I know that the solution could be to create a different struct with the `Password` as type `string` like following and add it to the controller, so that `BindJSON` works properly:

```
type user struct {
    Password string `json:"password" binding:"required"`
}
```

This solution does not reflect my model and I need to add extra code. How can I adapt my model/context binding?

Comment: There is not an option to change the JSON decoder's expectation that the value for a []byte is  base64 encoded.  Use two struct types.

Comment: There is no `[]byte` in json. The runtime thinks `[]byte` is binary data and tries to encode it in base64 string. If your DB model doesn't match your API model, you have two separate models.

Comment: This is a classic case for the use of DTOs. You shouldn't be mapping things coming from your api directly into your model, as you just ran into one of the many possible issues with that. Might sound cumbersome at first, but the way to go is to really have specific structs to map what's coming in and out from your app, hence DTOs (data transfer objects). Here's a great subject on the topic: https://professionalbeginner.com/the-dto-dilemma